# AFNetworking - How to make POST request by ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, afnetworking

I'm quite new to iPhone development, and I'm using AFNetworking as my services library.

The API i'm querying is a JSON one, and I need to make POST requests to fetch the data by ID  where this is the detail view which fetched he News Image and Description and for the listing News i have used GET request and it's working fine in that GEt method i have NewsID. To do this, I tried with the following code :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"News_Id": @"2",
                             @"News_Id": @"3",
                             @"News_Id": @"5"};
[manager POST:@"http://almithaq.mawaqaademo.com/AlMithaqService/API.svc/getNews_ByID" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And added @"text/html", in acceptableContentTypes in AFJSONResponseSerializer now Getting the following error:

```
 2014-07-15 12:22:18.030 News[2541:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" 
(JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
UserInfo=0x8cf0060 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
 option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x8cefcb0 "Request failed: bad 
request (400)"}
```

Comment: You should use a GET request for fetching data. A POST request is for modifying data on the server (usually adding some object into a set). You need to consult the server API how to do this. If this were a RESTful API you usually fetch a certain object with a specified ID using a url like `http://example/api/news/123`, where the last path component is the ID, and the "news" component specifying the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a problem with the server. You might want to check if you need any credentials to access the data.

Comment: No in the postman if i give the { "News_ID" = 3 } i'm getting the post  sucessfully